# jQuery Masonry - AJAX returned data not picking up masonry grid layout after being appended

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

When I append AJAX returned data to my masonry container, it doesn't pick up the grid layout already applied to the previously loaded items. I'm using the following code wrapped in a document ready function:

```
// Masonry
var $container = $('#masonry-container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid_4',
        isAnimated: true
    });
});

// AJAX Fotolia Image Search
var morebtn = $('.get-more-results');
var sOffset = 50;
morebtn.on('click', function () {
    var $cst = $('.crrsrch').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "...",
        data: {};
        success: function (data) {
            $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
                $container.append(data);
                $container.masonry('appended', data);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The items from the AJAX call get appended but they don't have the masonry layout - they're floated at the top of the list rather than appearing appended. The data is being appended in the markup.

Using the Masonry appended method is throwing an error too. I'm getting the following in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'webkitMatchesSelector' of object is not a function
    i
    r._filterFindItemElements
    r._getItems
    r.addItems
    r.appended
    t.fn.(anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    doneLoading
```

Each of these relate to the masonry js file, apart from the last two ((anonymous function) and doneLoading).

From using the method documentation on the masonry site, this should work. Obviously I'm missing something here.

Extra information which might help -
- The AJAX call is to the Fotolia API
- The site is built on Wordpress 3.5.2
- The javascript files are being enqueued

If anyone has any ideas or could offer some help, it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Im having the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try declare masonry itemselector within the function(success) just as soon content is loaded also in a similarcase i encountered, helped to apply $container.masonry('reload');

eg:

```
success: function (data) {
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.append(data);
            $container.masonry('appended', data);
            $container.masonry({
              itemSelector: '.grid_4',
           });
             $container.masonry('reload');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Tieslog, I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

`function(data){

    //append received data into the element

   $container.append(data).masonry('reloadItems').masonry( 'layout' ); }`

Try this it was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to accomplish a reload functionality on Masonry is to go through these steps:

1-make a function like this(we're going to make use of this later on)

```
function masonriniate() {
      var $container = $('#news');
        // initialize
        $container.masonry({
          itemSelector: '.columns',
        });
    }
```

2- In your script before initiating your ajax call destroy masonry completely like this:

```
$('#news').masonry('destroy');
```

3- after your ajax completion make use of methods like .ajaxComplete( handler ) or any event listener that is waiting for your ajax call to complete run this function:

```
window.setTimeout(masonriniate, 500);
```

just keep in mind that the timeout is important if you have any kind of transition or animation going on, just make timeout milliseconds more than animation timeout

happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

clearly explained here https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended that you should wrap your response in jquery object and then append. Change this portion of your code.

```
success: function (data) {
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        var $data = $(data);
        $container.append($data);
        $container.masonry('appended', $data);
    });
}
```

will fix the problem.